# What does the operator `-gt` in shell scripts mean?

Tags: shell-script, shell, test

Hi I have this sentence and I want to know what does it means please.

```
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then   #  --> this is if the value of the parameter $1 is zero
    PASO=1
elif [[ "$1" -gt 1 ]] ; then  # but i don't know what this flags mean? .."-gt"
    LOG "[$(date +%T)] Parametros incorrectos"
    exit 255
else
    PASO=$1
fi
```

What does `-gt` mean?

Comment: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: `-z` tests for string _length_ zero, also called 'empty' or 'null', but not the string consisting of one character `0` used to represent the integer zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ help test
test: test [expr]
    Evaluate conditional expression.
...
      arg1 OP arg2   Arithmetic tests.  OP is one of -eq, -ne,
                     -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.

    Arithmetic binary operators return true if ARG1 is equal, not-equal,
    less-than, less-than-or-equal, greater-than, or greater-than-or-equal
    than ARG2.
```

Comment: On a UNIX system `help test`results in the message: `ERROR: Key 'test' not found (he1)` ;-)

Comment: @schily There are so many UNIX systems, and then so many more non-UNIX systems that most "UNIX" systems probably aren't. `help` is a bash built-in command and as such has not much to do with UNIX (as opposed to `man` which is usually an executable and was probably about the third command conceived during the development of UNIX, after `sh` and `cc`). If you try `man test` you'll get a description of a command which you probably never execute but which is helpful anyway because the various shell built-ins faithfully emulate its original behavior.

Comment: @schily, what shell are you using on "UNIX"?

Comment: `help` is a command that is part of `SCCS`. Shells that introduced a builtin named `help` with different behavior show that their author did not try to inform himself about existing practice before creating that builtin.

Comment: @schily On the contrary: Any proprietary software offering executables named `help` (or `test`, or `exit`, or any other of a number of common English words) is immediately self-disqualified because they likely didn't think much about a number of other critical decisions either.

Comment: Do `help test`, bash has is built in an an optimization only. The non-built in one should be available on all Unixes (except busybox only).

Comment: Well, the `help` builtin in bash is proprietary, the external `help`command is UNIX standard software since 1977. So bash disqualifies itself.

Comment: OK, `help` is problematic. `man test` and/or https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: @schily I admit I was cocky. For example I didn't know that sccs and Unix were so close. I wrote a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446843/90785) regarding `sccs help`.

Answer (score 14):

`-gt` means "greater than".  It is used to compare integers for the inequality that is usually written `>` in other languages (in some shells, with the `test` utility or inside `[ ... ]`, `>` compares two strings for lexicographical ordering, so it has a very different meaning from `-gt`).

`-gt` is documented in the manual for `test` or `[`, or in your shell's manual if these are built-in utilities, as

> `n1 -gt  n2`
>
> True if the integer `n1` is algebraically greater than the integer `n2`; otherwise, false.

(the above is taken from [the POSIX standard text about the `test` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/test.html))

Fortran also uses this abbreviation in its `.GT.` relational operator for numbers.

The other relevant operators for comparing integers in the shell with `test` or in `[ ... ]` are `-ge` ("greater-than or equal"), `-lt` ("less-than"), `-le` ("less-than or equal"), `-eq` ("equal") and `-ne` ("not equal").

Interestingly, *all* of these are the same in Fortran (`.GT.`, `.GE.`, `.LT.`, `.LE.`, `.EQ.` and `.NE.`).

Answer (score 3):

You can start with `help test`, which will display the help of the POSIX subset of the syntax supported by the `[[` operator.

A comprehensive documentation is in the `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section of `man bash`.

Specifically:

```
Other operators:
  ...
  arg1 OP arg2   Arithmetic tests.  OP is one of -eq, -ne,
                 -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.

Arithmetic binary operators return true if ARG1 is equal, not-equal,
less-than, less-than-or-equal, greater-than, or greater-than-or-equal
than ARG2.
```

Comment: Yes I know that... what i need to know is what does it means " -gt " :-D

Comment: Read that section of the man page, it's documented right in there.

Comment: I'd say "display the help of the POSIX subset of the syntax supported by the **[** operator" because `[[...]]` is actually part of the bash grammar, while `/bin/[` is a POSIX command.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - `/bin/[` is a command line tool, `[` is a Bash built-in, and `[[` is a Bash operator. With my statement I wanted to emphasize that the `[[` is a Bash extension of the POSIX `[`.